# Openerp - How to call a custom botton on tree view header area

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am using Openerp 7 and I need to call a custom button on tree view header area (next to Create or Import). Is it possible to do so ?

**This is how the button Which I need to move;**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="edit_roster_substitution_form">
            <field name="name">leave.score.card.form</field>
            <field name="model">leave.score.card</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Leave Score Card"  version="7.0">
                 <sheet>

                        <button string="Generate" type="object" name="populate_values" class="oe_highlight"/>

                   </sheet> 
                   </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

[image]

**Tree view** ,

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_leave_score_card_tree">
            <field name="name">leave.score.card.tree</field>
            <field name="model">leave.score.card</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <tree string="Leave Score Card To the Date" colors="red:available_medical &lt; 0.0; red:available_casual &lt; 0.0">                     
                        <field name="employee_id"  />
                        <field name="category_id" />
                        <field name="taken_medical" />
                        <field name="taken_casual" />
                        <field name="taken_annual" />
                        <field name="taken_spc" />      
                        <field name="available_medical" />
                        <field name="available_casual" />
                        <field name="available_annual" />
                        <field name="available_spc" />
                        <field name="sec_id" invisible="1" />
                        <field name="division_id" invisible="1" />
                        <field name="departmnt_id" invisible="1" />
                        <field name="comp_id" invisible="1" />
                        <field name="total_taken_leaves" invisible="1"/>

                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

[image]

**This is my action window and menu call**

```
<record id="open_leave_score_card" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Leave Score Card To the Date</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">leave.score.card</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,graph,form</field>
            <field name="view_id" eval="view_leave_score_card_tree"/>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_leave_score_card_search"/>
        </record>

    <menuitem name="Leave Score Card" action="open_leave_score_card" id="menu_open_view_leave_score_card" parent="base.menu_reporting_dashboard" />
```

**This is my function**

```
def populate_values(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):

        result = {'value': {}}
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        tt=today.date()
        emps=self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('current_status','=','active')], context=context)
        if emps:

            for employees in emps:

                #result['value']['employee_id'] = employees
                print employees

                holiday_obj=self.pool.get('hr.holidays')
                holiday_emps_allocate=holiday_obj.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id','=',employees),('type','=','add'),('state','=','validate')], context=context)
                holiday_emps_taken=holiday_obj.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id','=',employees),('type','=','remove'),('state','=','validate')], context=context)

                .
                .
                .
```

**What I am expecting is**

[image]

Is it possible to do so ??

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TePJy.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BFVG.jpg
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have changed the question and did as you asked. Please help me with this

Comment: These will take a lot efforts to do that. These is alternative way. Why not add menu under *Action* center of Tree view. As you click any record from Tree view, you can see it. In that place we may add menu *Generate*

Comment: in that way or I can do with converting this function in to on-load function but the thing is I have no idea how to write on-load function in Openerp,

Comment: put button in `header` section of xml, this not make exactly how you wish, but get closer. Is possible make exactly how you show in image, but take a lot efforts, you have to change javascript too. If button in `header` section dont fit your need, I can help you to solve this.

Comment: @Odedra - Thank you so much for your kind support. I have tried it and showed to the people who going to work with this, but they want a clear view of the "Generate Report" part.

Comment: @gabrieloliveira - But we can't call header tag inside the tree view , can we ? but any way thanks for the reply and of course I need help

Comment: @SwanWhite Sorry, `header` only works in `form` tag.

Comment: @SwanWhite You solve your problem?

Comment: @gabrieloliveira - nah, I just call a button in form view and make it re-direct to the form view. I know it's a crappy job but for the moment it works. But I need to know how to do this any way.